# Bluetooth: internet connection sharing and hands free at the same time

Tags: bluetooth, internet-sharing, accessories

Can someone confirm whether they have got the following working (I think it should work), and whether there are any problems in practice on Win 10 Mobile / WinPhone 8.1?

I am looking at having the following connected at the **same time**

- Internet sharing (via Bluetooth PAN) with one device (eg. a satnav in a car)
- Handsfree (via Bluetooth HFP / A2DP) with a different device (eg. a car stereo)

In addition, if everything is set up correctly in Gadgets and Bluetooth on the phone is turned on, will the two devices connect automatically without having to do anything? (assume that nothing is required for the other two devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this and it works fine.